# How do I create dataframe from a collection of Rows?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a dataframe manually from parsed string RDD. I have my StructType already and I can able to create a Row object from `RowFactory.create(StructType[])`. I see a method called `sqlContext.createDataFrame(RDD<Row>, StructType)` that takes RDD and StructType. So how do I turn my Row object into an RDD?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your parsed string is all in driver memory. If not you will have to create a `RDD<String>` using `sc.textFile` and then map it to `RDD<StructType>`.

You can use `sc.parallelize` to convert your `StructType[]` array or list to rdd. You don't need to convert it into a row. Make sure that StructType object is serializable.

I haven't done spark in java so I might have some syntax error, but here's the basic idea.

```
//say you have a list of structType in memory
List<StructType> structTypeList = Lists.newArrayList(structTypeObj1, structTypeObj2);

//now convert it to an rdd
JavaRDD<StructType> rdd = sc.parallelize(structTypeList);
```

Comment: I need the Row to be serialized, not structTypes. createDataFrame takes in RDD<Row> and I just have Row. I think I have the answer for the most part. You need to create a Row RDD from transformation of RDD<String>